# How to add Gravartar To Open Cart Admin Area

Tags: php, opencart

Hi I am trying to add a gravatar image to my header of my open cart admin area I can only get the default image of gravatar image to show up.

I am after trying to get it so when admin user logged on it will show up with there gravatar image if user has uploaded there image to gravatar profile

As i said can only seem to get the default image of the gravatar.

the files I am working with are open cart admin controller/ header.php and view/header.tpl

In view file admin / view / template / common header.tpl

```
<li>
<a href="" class="text-center">
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<?php echo md5(strtolower(trim($user_info['email']))); ?>" /> 
</a>
</li>
```

Not sure why not picking up admin users email and gravatar image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities:

1. Email don't have a gravatar image.
2. Empty email id - generates: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e - default gravatar image.

From your comments I understood that you're passing an empty value for email.

Update `system/library/user.php` as below:

After: `$this->username = $user_query->row['username'];`

Add: `$this->email = $user_query->row['email'];`

---

Before: `public function getUserName() {`

Add:

```
  public function getUserEmail() {
    return $this->useremail;
  }
```

---

Change : `$user_info['email']` in your code

To : `$this->user->getUserEmail();`

Have a niceday :) !!

Comment: Did not work for open cart. I need it to pick up admin users email so if email is conected with gravatar

Comment: Are you getting the email in the variable `$user_info['email']` ?

Comment: I tried to from admin/controller/header.php by just copying code from user did not work i have this function get_gravatar in header.php admin

Comment: So you are passing an empty value as  $user_info['email'] ?

Comment: Did what you said nothing happend?